# anaconda build system don't work in sublime text 3

Tags: anaconda, sublimetext3

eve : virtual box ubuntu16.04

I installed sublime text 3, and installed the plugin-in anaconda.
i configured the Anaconda.sublime-settings:

```
{
    "anaconda_linting" : false,
    "swallow_startup_errors": true,
    "python_interpreter": "/home/cgy/soft/anaconda3/bin/python"
}
```

it's seem all ok, but when i make an .py file and build it ,such as that:

```
import pandas as pd
print("hello")
```

Can't find the build system, then i do that:tools->build system->new build system
create an file,and the content is that:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": ["/home/cgy/soft/anaconda3/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

but the sublime console just out put:

```
  File "/home/cgy/soft/sublime_text_3/sublime_plugin.py", line 795, in run_
  return self.run(**args)
  File "exec in /home/cgy/soft/sublime_text_3/Packages/Default.sublime-
  package", line 238, in run
  TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

what's wrong it and how should i do to solve it?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is being generated because your build system is incorrectly using `shell_cmd` when you seem to have meant `cmd` instead.

If you use `shell_cmd`, the value should be a string that represents exactly what you would type into a command prompt, complete with things like redirection, `&&` to chain commands, etc.

If you use `cmd`, the value should be an array of strings, where the first one is the name of the thing to run and the rest are the arguments.

To fix your problem you need to use `cmd` instead, or convert the list of strings into a complete string. If you go the latter route, be sure that you remember that you need to take care of quoting things like `$file` if your filename has spaces.